# Please help me understand the reason for flag rejection in this post

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Yesterday, I raised a "not an answer" flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958563/2173917).

It got rejected as

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

*My arguments in support of my choice:*

1. The post (answer) is mostly irrelevant to the question, keeping apart *technical inaccuracies*.
2. It "does not provide answer" to the question asked by OP, that's why I though it is eligible for NAA.
3. (To a newbie) It is misleading at its best.

So, I raised the flag to delete the *answer*, but it is rejected. With all due respect, I would like to know the counter-arguments to my thoughts.

Comment: It is an answer.  A rather brilliant one judging from the low odds that a causal reader can see the connection to the question.  Which is a poor one so anything is possible.  Use a vote instead of a flag to indicate (the lack of) brilliance, you can't expect a moderator to judge the technical merit of a post.  Fwiw, it is shoddy questions like this not getting close-voted anymore that causes these kind of mishaps.

Comment: As somebody with no knowledge of C, that looks like an attempt to answer the question to me. And that's the benchmark we're using here. Can somebody who knows absolutely nothing about the subject tell that it's *not* an attempt to answer?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Well,sir, even if we consider your point, does it _look_ like an answer to you? What was the problem? What do i need to do to resolve that? I don't see the answer addressing those basic queries. Doesn't it read like a _general statement_? What say?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It looks like a very low quality answer that's in serious need of improvement, but an honest attempt to answer nonetheless. It sounds like you need to indent your preprocessor directive as demonstrated in the answer. Whatever that means they seem to believe that it will fix the problem.

Comment: Mods are janitors. Janitors sweep the floors and mop up vomit. They don't grade your trig homework. You wouldn't *want* a janitor to grade your trig homework. Don't ask them to grade your trig homework.  In other words, they are [monkeys who has guns in there hands](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png). You can't expect a monkey to have the ability to judge an answer based on the technology in question. You expect them to shoot stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like an attempt at an answer to me. I wouldn't delete it withough knowing if indentation is the problem with the OP's code. Since that's a technical issue, it's not for moderators to decide. Use a downvote if the answer is wrong, not a flag.

Answer (score 9):

It is an answer and it should not be flagged. It should be down voted so 20K+ users can delete it.

The poster was obviously incorrect, but they apparently *thought* that changing the formatting would fix the problem. It wasn't just a side comment saying "your code is ugly, you should make it look nicer" - it was an *attempt* at resolving the problem.